# how to check if value in table exists in another table in stored procedures oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

Hello i am trying check whether a data in a table is exists in another table or not
Here's my code

i tried 2 methods but both doesn't work idk why
method 1

```
create or replace procedure proc1
As
Begin
if not exists(select * from T2 where c=(select * from (select * from T1 order by c) where rownum=1)) then
insert into T2
select * from (select * from T1 order by c) where rownum=1
end if;
End;
```

method2

```
create or replace procedure proc1
As
Begin
declare var integer;
select count(*) into var from (select * from T1
intersect
select * from T2)
group by c
if var<2 then
insert into T2
select * from (select * from T1 order by c) where rownum=1
end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need PL/SQL and can use a single SQL `merge` statement:

```sql
create or replace procedure proc1
As
Begin
  MERGE INTO t2
  USING (
    SELECT a, b, c, d, e
    FROM   t1
    ORDER BY c
    FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
  ) t1
  ON (t1.c = t2.c)
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (a, b, c, d, e)
    VALUES (T1.a, T1.b, T1.c, T1.d, T1.e);
End;
/
```

or an `INSERT` with `NOT EXISTS` and a correlated sub-query:

```sql
create or replace procedure proc1
As
Begin
  INSERT INTO t2
  SELECT *
  FROM   (
    SELECT *
    FROM   t1
    ORDER BY c
    FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
  ) t1
  WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                     FROM   t2
                     WHERE  t1.c = t2.c );
End;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_kQOaFH5)